# WebView crashing loading videos for Android 7.0

Tags: android, webview, android-7.0-nougat

I have been looking into this issue for a few days now and haven't been able to sort this out. The issue I am having with WebViews is when I load a vimeo video it will fail with this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.getDefaultVideoPoster(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:1181)
at org.chromium.android_webview.DefaultVideoPosterRequestHandler$1.run(DefaultVideoPosterRequestHandler.java:39)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Now the strange thing is this is happening on Anroid 7.0 and not anything lower then Android 4.4 (Don't have physical devices for 5.0 or 6.0 to test on).

Here is my code that I am running to render the fragment:

```
public class FragmentWebView extends Fragment{

protected WebView myWebView;
private String title, url, message;
private boolean isOffline;
View vWebView;
ViewFinder viewPullDowns;
SwipeRefreshLayout srlWebview;

protected void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
protected void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    vWebView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_web_frame, container, false);

    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setToClose();
    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setTitle(title);

    init();

    return vWebView;
}

private void init() {
    viewPullDowns = new ViewFinder((ViewGroup)vWebView, "pulldown");
    srlWebview = (SwipeRefreshLayout)  vWebView.findViewById(R.id.srl_fwf_webview);

    if(message == null) {
        message = "Unable to connect";
    }

    initWebView();

    srlWebview.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            if(url != null) {
                myWebView.loadUrl(url);
            }
        }
    });
}

private void initWebView() {
    myWebView = (WebView) vWebView.findViewById(R.id.webview);

    if(url != null) {
        try {
            WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
            webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
            myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
            myWebView.loadUrl(url);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }else{
        initOffline();
    }
}

protected void initOffline() {
    myWebView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorTransparent));
    viewPullDowns.setAllViewsVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).showMessageOnBottom(message, R.color.colorError);
    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).hideSubmenu();
    isOffline = true;
    srlWebview.setRefreshing(false);
    }
}
```

This error occurs occasionally and if I uninstall my app it will start working again. It seems like the WebView is caching null object then loading them (not 100% sure on that). Has anyone else experience this issue before or has looked into alternative libraries that support browsing the web inside of a fragment?

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46886701/webview-crashes-when-displaying-a-youtube-video. It might work out for you.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46886701/webview-crashes-when-displaying-a-youtube-video