# crash at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.getDefaultVideoPoste

Tags: android, android-webview

Actually i have openned a live stream url within a android `webview` and getting a issue of null pointer of `bitmap.getwidth()`. so my question is it is need to fix from android app or from the server side? Not getting the line no or other things to fix it. any idea

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
       at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewContentsClientAdapter.getDefaultVideoPoster(WebViewContentsClientAdapter.java:1142)
       at org.chromium.android_webview.DefaultVideoPosterRequestHandler$1.run(DefaultVideoPosterRequestHandler.java:39)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
```

Comment: Here is also answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46886701/webview-crashes-when-displaying-a-youtube-video/47087335

Answer (score 3):

Add below code to your CustomChromeClient;

```
@Nullable
@Override
public Bitmap getDefaultVideoPoster() {
    if (super.getDefaultVideoPoster() == null) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    } else {
        return super.getDefaultVideoPoster();
    }
}
```

it should work with this workaround:

In Kotlin:

```
override fun getAssets(): AssetManager {
    return resources.assets
}
```

In Java:

```
@Override
public AssetManager getAssets() {
    return getResources().getAssets();
}
```

Comment: I LOVE YOUU <333333 Thanksss

Comment: So many years passed since your answer and it fixed my issue that I pulled my hair 7 days to fix. THANK YOU MAN!